# how to click on second panel of Accordion yii widget on page load?

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-extensions

**i am using following YII widget Code**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAccordion',array(
'panels'=>array(
    'panel 1'=>'content for panel 1',
    'panel 2'=>'content for panel 2',
    // panel 3 contains the content rendered by a partial view
    //'panel 3'=>$this->renderPartial('_partial',null,true),
),
// additional javascript options for the accordion plugin
'options'=>array(
    'animated'=>'bounceslide',
),
));
```

**i want to click on panel 2 and display data on page load, ,what should i do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass zero-based index of opened panel via options `active` parameter, as it described here: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active. In your case the code will be:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAccordion',array(
    'panels' => array(
        'panel 1' => 'content for panel 1',
        'panel 2' => 'content for panel 2',
        // panel 3 contains the content rendered by a partial view
        //'panel 3' => $this->renderPartial('_partial',null,true),
    ),
    // additional javascript options for the accordion plugin
    'options' => array(
        'animated' => 'bounceslide',
        'active' => 1,
    ),
));
```